# Windows style getopt/argp

Tags: c++, windows

Is there a windows equivalent to `getopt` or `argp` that simplifies the writing of 
a windows command line tool?

It should contain argument parsing and enforcing the Windows style of argument syntax and perhaps providing assistance to syntax for executors.

The windows command line tools has a certain style that makes me think there is such a tool. The SO questions I have found indicates that translations of getopt are my best bet.

Comment: There is not really a good equivalent.  I'm sure there's a number of 3rd party command line parser classes, but there's nothing as standardized as getopt.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Boost Program Options

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/program_options.html

Comment: Very good answer. Unfortunately the target audience does not have boost available.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: Windows conventions are quite easy to enforce: `/s[:something]` and  `/?` summarizes pretty much everything. It should not be very difficult to write something from scratch (I have done it in C# a few years ago).

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: Sample code from microsoft seems to indicate that a direct approach is manageable: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppWindowsService-cacf4948/sourcecode?fileId=21604&pathId=1975374765

Comment: I really appreciate your effort, however; as you surely know argp and getopt makes a 5 hour job turn into a one hour job with the added bonus of a common syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this port for windows
https://github.com/tom42/argp-standalone
it tries to provide the same functionality, this will help you if you want to port a known utility that already uses argp.

In case you're writing from scratch, you can use glib (C), or CLI11 (C++).